# Concatenating instead of summing up (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function, concatenation, addition, innerhtml

I am new to JavaScript, I've searched a lot in the web but I can't solve my problem. I know that "InnerHtml" could be the problem and already tried some solutions but nothing seems to work.

Here's my code:

```
        function compra() {

        dinero = document.getElementById("precio").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("tipoo").innerHTML;
        total = dinero+total; 
        document.getElementById("compra").innerHTML = total;
```

The problem is that went using the button to show the result, it doesn't add the values, just concatenate them.

I already tried "parseInt" but doesn't work, or maybe I put it in the wrong place.

Thanks.

Edit-----

Thanks for quickly replies guys... when I use parseFloat or Int I get the "NaN".

Here is more of my code... hope it helps.

Total De Compra: $
 Añadir a la Lista

Comment: It would be helpful to see how the nodes "precio" and "tipoo" look like in the HTML - please provide a little code to demonstrate the content

Comment: use more pluses: `total = +dinero + +total;` or go semantic with `Number(dinero)`

Answer (score 3):

`innerHTML` returns strings. If you want to treat them as numbers and add them, you have to convert them.

```
total = parseFloat(dinero) + parseFloat(total);
```

Comment: Watch out if you use this, OP. You're wanting `parseInt` otherwise you'll come across the famous [floating point rounding error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0). Take `parseFloat(0.2) + parseFloat(0.1)` for example, you'll come out with `0.30000000000000004`. Watch the video I linked for more information.

Comment: @JordanDoyle If he has decimals in his input, he'll get `0` as the result, which is even more wrong.

Comment: @JordanDoyle looks like the values in the OP may have fractional parts, so `parseInt()` would be a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah seems like he's dealing with prices. Probably best if he uses `parseFloat` then calls `toPrecision(2)` from the return of it.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a weakly typed language. So there is some "magic" that happens. When you are using the + operator, it will add the sum of both values if both values are numbers. Otherwise it will do string concatenation.

Using "window.parseInt" is the trick. (or window.parseFloat if you are working with decimal numbers).

change:

```
    total = dinero+total;
```

to:

```
    total = window.parseInt(dinero) + window.parseInt(total);
```

This will turn a number as a "string" to an actual number.

Comment: don't use parseInt for this, Number is more reliable. also, no need to prefix "window."

Comment: @JordanDoyle: sure, i can back that reliability up: `alert(parseInt("013"))` in IE8, or `alert(parseInt("13.25"))` in any browser...

Comment: As I said in my comment, use `parseFloat` if you are working with decimal numbers. It's common to use `parseInt` over `parseFloat` if you know that the value is going to be an integer.

Comment: i'm of the opinion that you should only use parseInt() to convert non-decimal bases or "dirty integers" like `55px`...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by non-decimal bases, but yes, I agree that you should use `parseInt()` with dirty integers such as `55px`, or `parseFloat()` with dirty floats such as `33.3%`, etc...

Comment: i mean to turn "101110101" or "FF" into a decimal

Comment: `parseInt` will floor the numbers, ex: `parseInt('77.3')  + parseInt('77.3')`  = 144, you should use parseFloat instead. also, no need for `window`

Answer (score 0):

Based on other answers ([Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)) and comments ([Jordan Doyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2132800/jordan-doyle)) the best option is to use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and if the number is inferior to `1` use [toPrecion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision).

why [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) is incorrect for this case ?

```
parseInt('77.3') + parseInt('77.3') = 144  //incorrect
```

So we use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```
parseFloat(77.3) + parseFloat(77.3) = 144.6 // correct
```

But then we've a problem...if we try:

```
parseFloat(0.1) + parseFloat(0.2)
```

the result will be

```
 0.30000000000000004
```

So my solution to this problem is:
If the number is inferior to `1` we use [toPrecision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) :

```
total = parseFloat(0.1) + parseFloat(0.2)
if( total < 1){
total = total.toPrecion(2) // 0.3 Correct
}
```

Answer to the question:

```
function compra() {
 dinero = document.getElementById("precio").innerHTML;
 document.getElementById("tipoo").innerHTML;
 total = parseFloat(dinero) + parseFloat(total)
 if( total < 1){
  total = total.toPrecion(2);
 }
 document.getElementById("compra").innerHTML = total;
}
```